# Advanced link category functionality Window fix Problem

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm just working on a wordpress theme and suddenly find out this problem with the link function in the body post section. when it click the windows is out of margins cause the dropdown's width is huge:

[image]

Does anybody know how to fix this window????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out the CSS class that controls the text boxes and set a fixed size on it. If it is a drop down then you have to limit the text length that can be shown. You can also view your database to ensure you don't have an entry there that is just worded too long.